Why Allah don't guide or show path to the misguided if he loves more than a mother?
I believe Allah loves his beings more than their mothers and at the same time I believe he is Al-Adl( the just). I want to know why he not guide the people by putting them in situation where they can learn about Allah. Why he judges us when he doesn't guide us when we were doing wrong.
Please I need answer.

Who says He doesn't?

74 And [mention, O Muhammad], when Abraham said to his father Azar, "Do you take idols as deities? Indeed, I see you and your people to be in manifest error."
75 And thus did We show Abraham the realm of the heavens and the earth that he would be among the certain [in faith]
76 So when the night covered him [with darkness], he saw a star. He said, "This is my lord." But when it set, he said, "I like not those that disappear."
77 And when he saw the moon rising, he said, "This is my lord." But when it set, he said, "Unless my Lord guides me, I will surely be among the people gone astray."
78 And when he saw the sun rising, he said, "This is my lord; this is greater." But when it set, he said, "O my people, indeed I am free from what you associate with Allah.
—Surat Al-'An`am 74-78

Abraham was not raised in a society of believers to teach him righteousness. He did not have a believing father to guide him toward the correct path.
But what guidance did Abraham receive here? Were angels sent from on high, or commandments carved in stone by His finger, or fabulous miracles performed that would leave witnesses on their knees in awe?
No. Allah showed Abraham the night sky, and from that alone Abraham was able to find God.
The signs of Allah are all around us, and His guidance comes in any number of forms. What matters is whether your heart is open to receive this guidance when it does come.
